# Why won't Catalina allow app to find hard drive

Tags: mac, java, usb-flash-drive, macos-catalina

I have an app that runs on Catalina, and that app requires a flash drive to license and authenticate the program. The flash drive works fine for all other Mac (and Windows) OS, but fails for Mac OS 10.15 specifically.

I found a workaround - run the application from terminal and it discovers the flash drive, no problem. But I don't want to run from terminal every time I want to use this app - Any ideas how to fix this annoying issue with the latest Mac OS release? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check with the developer for an update? System updates sometimes expose latent bugs in existing apps. It's not uncommon for app developers to have to issue updates to fix their previously-hidden bugs after a new OS release comes out.

Comment: Yes, but was there some security update (or similar) in Catalina that is causing this? If so, any ideas how to bypass that security in preferences (or elsewhere)?

Comment: Clearly it's possible for properly written apps to do this, as your app already does it correctly when launched a different way. Why would Catalina have a security measure that was so easily defeated?

Comment: Yes I see your point - However, also, I would just simply like to know why it works from terminal but not when I run the application normally? Why should that make any difference (clearly there must be a difference, but I'm not sure what it would be)? Thanks again.